# How to move my python scripts to the right path when installing setup.py?

Tags: python

I have been reusing several python projects and when I execute `python setup.py install` all the code gets copied into /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Now I am trying to create my own Python project and this is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "My project",
    version = "0.1",
    license = "BSD",
    packages=find_packages(),

)
```

However, that copies all my scripts into a /build directory which gets created in the directory where the setup.py is. How can I change that behaviour and so that the scripts move to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages instead?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the package first and that package ends up in `/dist`. Once you have the package file you have to install it with `pip install`. It will then be transferred to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

The purpose of creating packages is for distributing your code, so it assumes that you won't just be using it yourself and builds a package that can then be installed.

You won't be allowed to directly write to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` unless you use `sudo` because it is a system directory.

Also direct installation is not recommended because you might get something wrong and have to uninstall. It is always a safer and better practice to build the package and test it in a virtual environment before you actually install it.